# drupal login not working offline because of reCAPTCHA

Tags: database

I have installed a drupal site completely offline on my local machine I have it running on mysql and apache2. When I got to the localhost/user/login to edit changes because I want to do it on my machine and not on the actual site. I get a recaptcha error because the site key isn't registered for localhost. Is there anyway I can bypass recaptcha so I can login and make changes?

Thank you

edit:
As suggested below I have tried using drush when I run the drush pmu recaptcha command I get the below error:

```
The drush command 'pmu recaptcha' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions
```

I have tried running:

```
sudo drush cache-clear drush
```

as they suggest but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstall recaptcha, can easily be done with drush

```
cd path/to/project
drush pmu recaptcha
```

drush is a command line utility for drupal and can be easily installed following this guide's setup drush section
[I can't backup my website on a shared server because memory runs out. What can I do?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254829/i-cant-backup-my-website-on-a-shared-server-because-memory-runs-out-what-can-i/254833#254833)

Comment: And I do this in the linux terminal or where? Sorry I am brand new to drupal.

Comment: yes ...see updated answer

Comment: Thank you I have tried doing this but now I get an error when runn the command I have posted it in the original question above.