# Why aren't I allowed to log in?

Tags: 7, users

I have a local setup for an online running Drupal 7 website on Ubuntu 14.04.
I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and I restored the local setup.

I can access the website on localhost, but it doesn't allow me to log in as administrator user nor as normal user, whereas everything is working fine on the production server.

What can the issue be?

Comment: are you running recaptcha ? or some other security module that does not recognize your local url ? maybe this can help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256130/drupal-login-not-working-offline-because-of-recaptcha/256133#256133 was the local setup working before upgradign ?

Comment: recaptcha already uninstalled.

Comment: Look in your log files for error messages usually with `tail -20 /var/log/apache2/error.log` you can get to your error log.

Also you can get a list of all enabled modules and revise your question.  You can get this from phpmyadmin or you can install drush.  For drush look at "setup drush" here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254829/i-cant-backup-my-website-on-a-shared-server-because-memory-runs-out-what-can-i/254833#254833.  If you have drush run `drush pml --status=enabled` to get a list of all modules enabled and drop the list or any errors in your question.

Comment: no error in apache log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad! 
after wasting days i come to know that the `rewrite` module was disabled. 
after enabling rewrite module all works 
thanks